# Getting a link to show only when logged in with html tag at quotation

Tags: php, session, if-statement

I'm having difficulty getting this to work, I keep getting errors on having a link show when the user is authenticated.  I have this similar code on other parts of my site and it works, but not here.

The code

```
 <div class=\"avatar\">
  <?php if (isset($_SESSION['access_token'])) 
  { echo "<a href='userfeed.php?uid={$uid}&{$username}'><img src=\"{$avatar}\">; }
  else 
  { echo "<img src=\"{$avatar}\">; } ?>
  </div>
```

The Error:

```
syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE
```

Edit: I've tried all the answers and no luck.. what I'm thinking is the place in the code might effect this.. so below is the whole main div:

```
      // display all user likes
      foreach ($result->data as $media) {
        $content = "<div id=box>";

       // output media
        if ($media->type === 'video') {
          // video

          $content .= "<div class=mainimg><video class=\"video-js vjs-default-skin\" controls preload=\"none\" width=\"170\" height=\"170\" poster=\"{$poster}\"
                       data-setup='{}'>
                         <source src=\"{$source}\" type=\"video/mp4\" />
                       </video></div><div class=midsection>{$comment}</div>";
        } else {
          // image

          $content .= "<div class=mainimg><a class=\"fancybox\" rel=\"group\" href=\"{$fullimage}\" title=\"<b>{$username}</b>&nbsp;-&nbsp;{$comment}\"><img src=\"{$image}\"></a></div><div class=midsection>{$comment}</div>";
        }


       // create lower section

        $content .= "<div class=\"pfooter\">

       <div class=\"avatar\">

      if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']))
      { <a href='userfeed.php?uid={$uid}&{$username}'><img src=\"{$avatar}\">; }
      else
      { <img src=\"{$avatar}\">; }


          </div>               
                        <p>$username</p>
                       <p><img class=\"heart{$id2}\" style=\"cursor:pointer\" src=\"img/heart.png\" onclick=\"likePic('{$id2}','\'{$username}\'')\">{$numlikes}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src=\"img/comment.png\">{$comcount}</p>

                     </div>";


        // output media


        echo $content . "</div>";
      }
```

This still gives me the same error. I take this statement out, works fine.

Comment: The syntax highlighting above shows you your error...

Answer (score 0):

`{ echo "<a href='userfeed.php?uid={$uid}&{$username}'><img src=\"{$avatar}\">; }`

You hae a syntax error here, you open a " at the start of the anchor, then re-open another pair for the `img` tag.

You also have the same problem on this line `{ echo "<img src=\"{$avatar}\">; } ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Error is here:

```
echo "<a href='userfeed.php?uid={$uid}&{$username}'><img src=\"{$avatar}\">;
```

You can use '  ""  ' or "  ''  ".But " ""  " or '  ''  ' are not accepted. And here you make error in the formatting of quotation. You didn't end the first double quotation of echo "

Replace that php code with this code.

```
if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']))
 {
  echo'<a href="userfeed.php?uid='.$uid.'&'.$username.'"> <img src="'.$avatar.'"></a>';
 }
else { echo '<img src="'.$avatar.'"\>'; }
```

Comment: So you're saying its supposed to be like this? `{ echo "<a href='userfeed.php?uid={$uid}&{$username}'><img src=\"{$avatar}\">"; }`

Comment: See at last you put double quotation in double quotation. That is not accepted syntax "{$avatar}\">". I have given a solution try with that.

Comment: echo'<a href="userfeed.php?uid={$uid}&{$username}">'.'<img src=\"{$avatar}\"></a>'; @BrandN00b

Comment: still getting the error with this, is this correct? `{ echo "<a href='userfeed.php?uid={$uid}&{$username}'>".'<img src=\"{$avatar}\"></a>'; }

    else 
    { echo "<img src=\"{$avatar}\">"; } ?>`

Comment: else      { echo "<img src=\"{$avatar}\">"; } ?> is wrong

Comment: Wow Muhammad - your examples are just as bad as the original. Why don't you just break out of quotes and concatenate for the pure ease of explaining the problem??

Comment: I wanted to made it in small way but @BrandN00b again fall in problem in else condition. I discuss about the formatting of the quotation and  gave the answer in the main answer.  scrowler

Comment: @BrandN00b now try, I have edited the answer. I think it will work In sha Allah.And waiting for your appreciation.

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste the following code

```
<div class="avatar">
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']))
{ echo "<a href='userfeed.php?uid={$uid}&{$username}'><img src=\"{$avatar}\">"; }
else
{ echo "<img src=\"{$avatar}\">"; }
?>
</div>
```

Your problem is in two echo you forget the last "

Comment: this looks correct, but i'm still getting the same error.. thinking its because of where it is in my code.. see above.

Comment: Now with all the context of your code, I added a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

See this part of your code:

```
$content .= "<div class=\"pfooter\">
<div class=\"avatar\">
if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']))
{ <a href='userfeed.php?uid={$uid}&{$username}'><img src=\"{$avatar}\">; }
else
{ <img src=\"{$avatar}\">; }
</div>
<p>$username</p>
<p><img class=\"heart{$id2}\" style=\"cursor:pointer\" src=\"img/heart.png\" onclick=\"likePic('{$id2}','\'{$username}\'')\">{$numlikes}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src=\"img/commen
t.png\">{$comcount}</p>
</div>";
```

Replace with this:

```
$content .= "<div class=\"pfooter\">"
."<div class=\"avatar\">"

if (isset($_SESSION['access_token'])) {
    $content .= "<a href='userfeed.php?uid={$uid}&{$username}'><img src=\"{$avatar}\">";
}
else {
    $content .= "<img src=\"{$avatar}\">;"
}

$content .= "</div>"
."<p>$username</p>"
."<p><img class=\"heart{$id2}\" style=\"cursor:pointer\" src=\"img/heart.png\" onclick=\"likePic('{$id2}','\'{$username}\'')\">{$numlikes}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src=\"img/comm
ent.png\">{$comcount}</p>"
."</div>";
```